# Edit a model comment Django

Tags: python, django

I am stuck because I want to add a comment in my model and I do not know how to do it.

Can you help me please ?

Here is my form in forms.py:

```
class UpdateActu(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Actu
        fields = ['commentaire']
        widgets = {
            'commentaire': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'exampleTextarea'})
        }
```

Here is my model :

```
class Actu(models.Model):
    commentaire = models.TextField(max_length=200, null=True)
    region = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.region
```

And here is my view :

```
def index_region(request,region):
\\I delete the other part to have better visibility
    form = UpdateActu()

    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, '../templates/index.html', context)
```

I know that currently, I just send my form but I do not know how to do the treatment to modify the old comment by the new one.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please research your issues yourself first before posting a question. This could have easily been solved through a simple google search.

Comment: This is basic Django forms: Read the documentation on [Django forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/) before asking. Try to write your view based on the documentation first, then if you're still stuck, ask on SO. Maybe take some time to actually do the [Django Tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial01/) from A-Z so you have an understanding of models, forms and views.

Answer (score 0):

First of all

```
region = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
```

you cannot make a CharField null I think. So instead use this:

region = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)

so it accepts a blank value because I see in your form you use the `commentaire` field but not the `region` field.

Second of all I need to see your view code to check if there is a problem with the view.

Answer (score 0):

To display my form I use javascript to click, it appears.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
               $('#modifier').click(function(){
                    $('#modification').append('{% for field in form %}<label class="my_class" for="{{ field.name }}">{{ field.label }} :</label>{{ field|escapejs }}{% endfor %}');
                    $('#test').show()
                    $('#commentaireActu').hide();
                });
            });
```